# Get the exact decimal representation of a JavaScript number

Tags: javascript

Every finite number in JavaScript has an exact real value. For example:

```
const x = Number.MAX_VALUE
```

Here, `x` has the precise value of 2<sup>1024</sup> - 2<sup>971</sup> =

> 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368

and we can demonstrate this by using `x` in arithmetic:

```
console.log(x % 10000) // 8368
```

But how can I get **all** of those decimal digits?

I'd like it if the solution also worked for non-integers, for example `const y = Number.EPSILON` is precisely 2<sup>-52</sup> =

> 0.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

Comment: Anything above `2^52` cannot be represented without loss of precision in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling - Not true.  The values that floating-point can exactly represent are represented without loss of precision.  And the OP is asking about those ones.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I see what you mean.

Comment: `toString(2)` gives you the binary representation if that helps ;) In fact, for any `x` except `10`, `toString(x)` returns a result that is not written in scientific notation. I don't think there is a built-in way to get that representation.

Comment: Ah, that might be good enough! Passing `'0b' + x.toString(2)` to a big decimal library like Decimal.js and then outputting from there may do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way I've found to do this is to

- write the float into an `ArrayBuffer`, then read it back as a 64-bit unsigned BigInt
- extract the sign, exponent and mantissa using bitwise operations
- compute the desired result *multiplied by a large power of 10*
- use string operations on the stringified BigInt to insert a decimal point in the right place.

For example:

```js
const SIGN_BITS = 1n
const EXPONENT_BITS = 11n
const MANTISSA_BITS = 52n
const BIAS = 1023n

export const stringify = value => {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') {
    throw Error('Not a number')
  }

  if (!Number.isFinite(value)) {
    return String(value)
  }

  const dataView = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8))
  dataView.setFloat64(0, value)
  const bigUint64 = dataView.getBigUint64(0)

  const mantissaBits = (bigUint64 >> 0n) & ((1n << MANTISSA_BITS) - 1n)
  const exponentBits = (bigUint64 >> MANTISSA_BITS) & ((1n << EXPONENT_BITS) - 1n)
  const signBits = (bigUint64 >> (MANTISSA_BITS + EXPONENT_BITS)) & ((1n << SIGN_BITS) - 1n)

  const sign = signBits === 0b0n ? '' : '-'

  const isSubnormal = exponentBits === 0b0n

  // So as to keep this in integers, multiply the fraction by 2 ** 52 while subtracting
  // that same power from the exponent
  const m = ((isSubnormal ? 0n : 1n) << MANTISSA_BITS) + mantissaBits
  const e = (isSubnormal ? 1n : exponentBits) - BIAS - MANTISSA_BITS

  if (e >= 0n) {
    // Pure integers, no problem
    return sign + String(m << e)
  }

  // Multiply by a large enough power of 10 that all possible decimal digits are preserved
  // when we then divide by the power of 2
  const power10 = 10n ** -e
  const f = (m * power10) >> -e
  const pre = f / power10
  const post = f % power10

  if (post === 0n) {
    return sign + String(pre)
  }

  return sign + String(pre) + '.' + String(post).padStart(Number(-e), '0').replace(/0+$/, '')
}

console.log(stringify(Number.MAX_VALUE))
```

This outputs:

> 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368

Similarly:

```
console.log(stringify(Number.EPSILON))
```

outputs:

> 0.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

Answer (score -2):

You mis understand floating point.

You get a max of about 14 digits as there is no more precision than. 2^52

The max number is a number that has three parts.

- The sign, positive or negative and is 1 bit. Thus you get 0 and -0
- The Fraction 52 bits that gives the precision of about 14 digits.
- The exponent 11 bits and is a signed value that is the amount to multiply the Fraction value with. 2 ^ exponent

See wiki [Double-precision_floating-point_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for more info.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not imprecise. Floating point *arithmetic* has limitations, because the result is rounded to the nearest available floating point number, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: It seems as if the OP **does** understand floating-point pretty well.  FP values **are** precise, and the OP is asking how to get the exact decimal representations of those values.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth 1.7976931348623157e+308 is what max val is as a double, rounded to the 291th digit You can not represent more than 2^64 states in 64bits, The number `Number.MAX_VALUE - 1` is meaningless, ie `Number.MAX_VALUE - 1 === Number.MAX_VALUE`  is true as is `Number.MAX_VALUE - 100000000 === Number.MAX_VALUE` how much can I take to change that?? try about 1e300 Doubles can not have any more precision than 2^52. Please read the wiki like I gave to understand why.

Comment: @qntm the MAX_VALUE is not a precise value, You read it as so but that is not what it represents.

Comment: @Blindman67 - You're stating that floating-point can't represent all reals.  That's correct.  But that's not the same as saying that they're imprecise.  Each floating-point value can be expressed as *2^exponent * (1 + sum(k = 1 -> 53) { m_k * 2^-k })*, which is unambiguously well-defined.  The OP is asking how to get the decimal representation of that value.  (As to **why** the OP wants that, well that's another question, of course ;)

Comment: You may as well say that the number 45,600,000,000 is "imprecise" because it has many trailing zeroes.

Comment: @qntm No that is not correct, that is an exact value.

Comment: @Blindman67 - And so are all floating-point values.  To put it another way, floating-point is not an [interval-arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) scheme; they don't represent ranges.  They represent specific real numbers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Please provide evidence for your argument, I provided a link, please show one that supports your argument.

Comment: Which argument? That floating-point values correspond to that mathematical expression? Or that that expression defines a unique real number?  The former is in the WP article you cited, the latter is just how maths works :)